# How to pass a variable to the next view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, global-variables

My app has an variable called `int antalratt`, which is the number of correct answers in that view. Now I want to pass that variable to the next view, where I want to get the number of correct answers to be shown! I know how to get an integer to a label text though!

The `int antalratt` is written in the `firstviewcontroller.m`, how do I make it "global" so that I can use it in the `secondviewcontroller`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using navigation controller, tabbar controller?

Comment: Sorry, Im new to programming so I maybe will answer some things wrong and so on ;)

First I have an tab bar controller, in the first view you are able to press a button in order to pick a certain test, then you are redirected to a new view controller where you get the questions, and when you hit a button that is shown after all questions the app will count the amount of correct answers and send you to a new view controller, where I want that number of correct answers to be shown!

Comment: Do not create global variables, period. Also do not attempt to exploit the app delegate for holding your model data. Even though both ways would function, you will regret it later on. Instead pass the values / objects from one viewController to the other to make the data flow transparent immediately to any other coder.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename *detailViewController = [[filename alloc] initWithNibName:@"filename" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.audio=@"yourData";
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Declare in filename.h

```
NSString *audio;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *audio;
```

and filename.m

```
@synthesize audio;


 -(void) ViewDidLoad
 { 
      NSLog(@"Audio = %@",audio);   // if ur variable is integer declare %d in nslog.
 }
```

thats all

Comment: what should the filename be? the first or the second view's name?

Comment: filename.h is the ur passed class name that is second view name

Comment: where should I put the first lines of code? Should I change "detailViewController?

Comment: In ur first class, when u navigate to next class

Comment: How do I get the vaiable on the next view?

Comment: the audio is the ur variable. print it in viewdidload method.

Comment: hmm, I dont have a viewdidload :O it is a UIView, not a UIViewController... what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

make a variable in the public interface of secondviewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *correctAnswers;
```

synthesize it in .m and then pass the value of antalratt in firstviewcontroller with `secondviewcontroller.correctAnswers = [NSNumber numberWithInt:antalratt];`

to secondviewcontroller. then set the labeltext

Comment: I wrote  Ra_ttning.antratt=[NSNumber numberWithInt:antalratt]; (Ra_ttning is the second view controller, ant antratt is what you called correctAnswers)
in the Fra_ga.m (which is the first view controller)

I also wrote this in the Ra_ttning.h:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Fråga.h"

interface Ra_ttning : UIView
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *rattningen;
    NSNumber *antratt;
    
    
}

property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *rattningen;
property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *antratt;



I synthesized antratt in the Ra_ttning.m as well.
I get an error saying"property 'antratt' not

Comment: found on object of type 'Ra_ttning'"

Comment: Do I have to import something or do anything in addition to what you wrote?

Comment: import Ra_ttning.h in Frag_ga.m

Comment: classname -> "Ra_ttning".antratt, you can't access a class without a object, you have to alloc and init it first. Ra_ttning *rattning = [[Ra_ttning alloc] initWithNibName:@"Ra_ttning" bundle:nil]; and then pass the value with rattning.antratt

Comment: where should I write the code Ra_ttning *rattning = [[Ra_ttning alloc] initWithNibName:@"Ra_ttning" bundle:nil];?

Comment: one line before rattning.antratt=[NSNumber numberWithInt:antalratt];

Comment: I get the error "No visible interface 'Ra_ttning' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'" at the line Ra_ttning *rattning = [[Ra_ttning alloc] initWithNibName:@"Ra_ttning" bundle:nil];

Comment: initWithNibName:@"yourXIBFilename" of Ra_tting-class

Comment: sorry? is there something that I should change? :P

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

RootViewController

```
-(IBAction)nextPage{

    int antalratt = 12;    // Value to be transfered

    FirstViewController * fvc = [[FirstViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    fvc.answer = antalratt;
    [self presentModalViewController:fvc animated:YES];
    [fvc release];

}
```

FirstViewController

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{

    int answer;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) int  answer;



@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize answer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%d",answer);   // //displays answer on log
}

@end
```

**Method 2 (AppDelegate)**

AppDelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

    int antalratt;
}
@property(nonatomic ,assign) int antalratt;
```

RootViewController

```
-(IBAction)nextPage{

    int antalratt = 12;    // Value to be transfered
    AppDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.antalratt = antalratt;

    FirstViewController * fvc = [[FirstViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:fvc animated:YES];
    [fvc release];
}
```

FirstViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    AppDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%d",delegate.antalratt);  //displays answer on log
}
```

**Method 3 (NSUserDefaults)**

RootViewController

```
-(IBAction)nextPage{
    int antalratt = 12;    // Value to be transfered
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:antalratt forKey:@"answer"];
    FirstViewController * fvc = [[FirstViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:fvc animated:YES];
    [fvc release]; }
```

FirstViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    int ans = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"answer"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",ans);  //displays answer on log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//
    view1.h

```
@interface view1 : UIView{

NSString *passingVariable;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *passingVariable;

@end
```

//

```
view1.m

@synthsize passingVariable;

@implementation view1

@end
```

// in another view

```
view2.m

#import "view1.h"

@implementation view2

-(IBAction)changeview

{

  view1 *myview = [[view1 alloc]init];

  myview.passingVariable = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello Variable"];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:myview animated:YES];

 }

@end
```

Comment: But I don't have an IBAction in the View2.m, the button in View1 should pass me to view2 and directly display the answer! What should I do then instead of this IBAction?

Comment: forget IBAction whereever you are trying to navigate this is what you have to do. :)

Comment: Do I have to make a UIViewController file? :O Because it is a UIView right now :O

Comment: Do you changed it ? and which template you are using

Comment: No I didnt change it! It was UIView from the beginning! I'm using a Tab bar template, I think! If that is what you mean!

Comment: :O i have never used this template but in case of empty tamplate i can tell u from scratch if you want :)

Comment: I'm close now! I've made the second view to change the label text to an int, but it always shows 0 :P in view2 viewdidload: ratttext.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",antratt];

in the code for the button that will make you go to view to, in view1:     Rattning *rattning = [[Rattning alloc] initWithNibName:@"Rattning" bundle:nil];
    rattning.antratt=[NSNumber numberWithInt:antalratt];

Comment: your antratt is int, so you cant make it strong and the value 0 you getting is the default value that means you are still not able to pass the value

Comment: my antratt is an NSNumber I think? :O what should I do instead of strong? ;P

Shiit this is hard... Easier to pass variables in like C# :P

Comment: Can you try to describe what I should do, very detailed? :P It has nothing to do with the tabs anymore I think, because in this state, there is no tabs anymore, just a UIView!

Info: 
Fråga is the first view, where the antalratt is counted
Rattning is the second view controller, where the antalratt should be transferred. The variable that should pick up antalratt there is antratt.